# Android File Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file, kotlin, uri, enoent

I am getting as error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/storage/FC73-12F9/AppList.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

when I try to run the following code on sndroid studio:

```
if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    var selectedFile = it.data?.data
    if (selectedFile !== null) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Filename: ".plus(selectedFile?.path))
        askForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,0x4);
        Log.i("MainActivity", File(selectedFile?.path).readText())
    }
}
```

`selectedFile?.path` is getting logged as `/root/storage/FC73-12F9/AppList.txt`

I am totally new to android development, can someone guide me on how to open a file from a given URI, `selectedFile` is an URI object and `selectedFile?.path` is the filepath.

> **Answer:**

This worked

```
applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedFile)
```

Comment: That is an impossible path. Not a real file system path. You got an uri. A content scheme. Use the uri. Dont try to get a path. Have a look at selectedFile?.string.

Comment: To read from the uri or open the file: InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedFile). Then read from the stream.